# console.log() in client from express server

Tags: javascript, html, express, backend, web-frontend

Is it possible to use console.log() in the backend (I am using express) to output things in the frontend.
for example:

```js
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
client.console.log('Hi');
```

How would I do it?
Thanks.

Comment: There is no built-in support for sending things to the front-end console in node.js.  You would have to build this yourself and would require some cooperating front-end and back-end code to implement.  As it stands now, this question is overly generic as it doesn't share any context for what circumstance you would want to do this in or why?  There are many possible ways to implement depending upon that context.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in support for a server to cause something to show in the client console.  I'm not sure what the actual use case for that is since the console is typically a debugging aid, not an actual end-user thing.

In any case, if you want to do that, you would have to have cooperating code on both the client and the server and then how that code works depends upon the context in which you want to put the info in the console.

**From a page load**

From a page load, the server could embed a small script in the page that would output into the browser console when the page loads and runs.

**From an Ajax call**

Here, you could include a property in some returned JSON that contains the desired console message and then the client code making the ajax call would have to grab that property and call `console.log()` with it.

**From any random time on the server**

If you're not in the context of an existing request from the browser or web page Javascript (as in the previous two points), then you would need some push channel connected between the web page and the server such as a webSocket connection, a socket.io connection or a SSE connection.   Then, you could send a message to the client and the client would need some code listening for those incoming messages and then display them in the local console upon receiving them.

Answer (score 0):

try  it:

The 'send' method of 'res' object of Express, is one of so many ways to send a response to client in the request event.

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  return res.send('Hello world!')
})
```

Comment: This is not what is being asked.

Comment: Really, there is no exact solution to what was asked, but I wanted to present another solution to the problem he had

Answer (score 0):

There is no support as jfriend00 said, but there is a way to go around this.
So lets say the user requests /test
You want to display`in his console` Hello World
So you do:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.get('/test', (req, res) => {
  return res.send('<script>console.log(Hello world!)</script>')
})
```

And that acts as a full client console log. There ya go. (Single Time)

Or setup socket.io as jfriend said in his post if you want to constantly post console messages (multiple times).

Comment: It should be `'<script>console.log("Hello world!")</script>'`